# Changing logo on different background colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a custom website where each section has a different background colour, on the scroll of each section the logo should change the colour of the logo is purple for eg. if the first section has a carousel and below there is a red background when scrolled the logo should change to white.

Comment: How have you created the varying backgound colors?

Comment: You could give each section a class based on the color of the section and then control the color of the logo with `hue-rotate` - [Read into it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/hue-rotate) or any other filter properties like `brightness`.

Comment: Share some codes so we could easily provide solutions.

Comment: You could use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to detect it the logo is overlapping the section an then change the color.

Comment: Yes each and every section has a different color @Teemu

Comment: I and  my buddies are trying to use javascript to change the logo on scroll using the window on scroll event code.

 $(function () { 
    $(".parent").scroll(function(){
      console.log($(this).attr("section0"));
    })
  });

Comment: Please provide some code so that we can suggest best feasible solution.

Comment: Yes, but how have you created the varying colors? Please show some code.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this example on your website. Hope it will help you.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style type="text/css">
            * {
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
          }
    
          body {
              font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
          }
          .row {
              min-height: 100vh;
              overflow: hidden;
              position: relative;
              width: 100%;
          }
    
          .logo {
              top: 100px;
              left: 100px;
              transform-origin: left top 0;
          }
    
          .startLogo {
              position: fixed;
          }
    
          .altLogo {
              position: absolute;
          }
    
          .white {
              color: white;
          }
    
          .black {
              color: #1d1d1d;
          }
    
          .grey {
              background: #ccc;
          }
    
          .blue {
              background: skyBlue
          }
    
          #scroll {
              position: fixed;
              bottom: 40px;
              right: 100px;
              text-align: center;
              font-family: arial
          }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="row grey ">
            <h1 class="logo black startLogo">Logo</h1> 
        </div>
    
        <div class="row blue">
            <h1 class="logo white altLogo">Logo</h1> 
        </div>
    
        <div id="scroll">SCROLL <Br/>   &#8595;</div>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function logoSwitch () {
              $('.altLogo').each(function() {
                $(this).css('top',
                  $('.startLogo').offset().top -  $(this).closest('.row').offset().top
                  );
            });
          };
    
          $(document).scroll(function() {logoSwitch();});
    
          logoSwitch();
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I will try to use it @Swati..thanks